# Is there any usual symbol for an algebraic structure?

Tags: linear-algebra

We're currently talking about algebraic structures in my classes and have defined what an algebraic structure is.

I'm wondering, though, is there any convention to name an algebraic structure? (you usually name functions $f, g, h$; points and sets with capitals)

Comment: There a large number of informal, unstated conventions. One might use $G,H,K$ for groups (and $H,K$ especially for subgroups), one might use $R$ or $S$ for rings, $M$ and $N$ for modules, $L,K,F$ for fields, one fraktur lowercase (like $\frak g,h$) for lie algebras, et cetera. There are simply too many to name or recall without cues.

Comment: I've seen the script font used, e.g. $\mathscr F$ or $\mathcal F$, but I don't know how widespread that is. (Code: `\mathscr`, `\mathcal`)

Answer (score 0):

Of which structures are you asking about? However there is no a generale rule; usually we use a couple with a capital letter and the symbol of the structure operation. For example if we have an adittive group, we can call it $ G $ and note the group structure in this way: $(G,+)$; if R is a ring we can write $(R,+,\cdot)$... but in practice, if is clear from the context of what we are speaking about, we just denote a group with G, a ring with R...

Comment: I mean **any** algebraic structure. For example here: $\textrm{an algebraic structure on set S is a collection  } ? = (S, \phi_{k_1},  \phi_{k_2}, ...,  \phi_{k_n})$